# The input is not a valid Base64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am receiving below token to my  asp.net core api from flutter mobile app , which I need to send to firebase api to verify my token and get firebase uid. My code in .net core is

```
   FirebaseToken decodedToken = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.VerifyIdTokenAsync(token);
   string uid = decodedToken.Uid;
```

I get the error as

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
> character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
> among the padding characters.

I tried adding '=' at the end to make the length divisible by 4 . But didnt work . Can anyone help ?

```
token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjZjZmMyMzViZDYxMGZhY2FlYzVlYjBhZGU5NTg5ZGE5NTI4MmRlY2QiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.N-fFCQHnJkdVcSqRQQ7XetEPQEeLCjOofjv3UogJlehLlUiJZhoKO6UWnb_liNxuTaFQ7tzvl03rHbm12na6KkhMup0J_UkC7HCyG6EtZmCgc8KmFRoYtHbztiCNI9v26QLPI_5C-KCnMDJdnvmGfuhh5NmmR5gC1LVuXMxZxaQFzcs1fkuA_8mCY1t4s0x0mQyeBUdrLVZnWdVSzM9-g1WZ0xrCrcsf7WTdWpuWeRmSIJSmNagP_l7R-uYUnTtwNISgFVn4mhSz4O1dqav7167TK2Z1PQD1QDhMA3FTIoYsc9izdlXQvmkbLxkq8dvhgxYVY"
```

Comment: There's dots, dashes and underscores... not sure if those are base64 characters.

Comment: It seems that you have a few invalid base64 chars in your string. Check the "_" and the "-" characters

Answer (score 4):

Dot is not an invalid token. It is a separator.
This token consists of three base64 encoded parts.
Take a look at repl:
https://repl.it/@AlieksandrAlie7/ZestyActiveOutput#index.js

Also, you may notice the last part contains invalid chars. According to the following table:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/stackabuse/media/decimal-to-base64-table.png

Maybe the replacement of invalid chars could work:

```
- => +
_ => /
```

Comment: Ah, these tokens are JWTs (https://jwt.io/), which explains the dots. Also, they use Base64 URL scheme https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications, which substitutes the characters as you point out.

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause of this issue is that the idToken you received was truncated in the console output, resulting in an invalid token. This is a reported issue, see [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665/), Flutter's `print()` method seems to only print a maximum of 1024-bit so a idToken is likely to be truncated. If you wish to get the token to appear fully, either:

- With debug mode, inspect the idToken value
- Without debug mode, use the `log(token)` method by `import 'dart:developer';` instead of `print()`